# How to fix LLDB: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException, if it's not an outlet mistake?

Tags: ios, xcode, firebase, lldb

I've looked for answers to this problem and it seems that the answer is always some outlet that was forgotten. But in my case, there's nothing of that.

I receive the message error everytime I call a certain Firebase method, but only when it's outside of a certain 'if-else'

Btw, the complete message:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[__NSPlaceholderDictionary initWithObjects:forKeys:count:]: attempt to insert nil object from objects[0]'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000102dffe65 __exceptionPreprocess + 165
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0000000102878deb objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000102d028ce -[__NSPlaceholderDictionary initWithObjects:forKeys:count:] + 318
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000102d14c3b +[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:forKeys:count:] + 59
    4   libert2                             0x0000000101757eb1 -[ViewController salvaridnofirebase] + 225
    5   libert2                             0x0000000101757b04 -[ViewController viewDidLoad] + 580
    6   UIKit                               0x000000010356af98 -[UIViewController loadViewIfRequired] + 1198
    7   UIKit                               0x000000010356b2e7 -[UIViewController view] + 27
    8   UIKit                               0x0000000103441ab0 -[UIWindow addRootViewControllerViewIfPossible] + 61
    9   UIKit                               0x0000000103442199 -[UIWindow _setHidden:forced:] + 282
    10  UIKit                               0x0000000103453c2e -[UIWindow makeKeyAndVisible] + 42
    11  UIKit                               0x00000001033cc663 -[UIApplication _callInitializationDelegatesForMainScene:transitionContext:] + 4131
    12  UIKit                               0x00000001033d2cc6 -[UIApplication _runWithMainScene:transitionContext:completion:] + 1760
    13  UIKit                               0x00000001033cfe7b -[UIApplication workspaceDidEndTransaction:] + 188
    14  FrontBoardServices                  0x00000001061c5754 -[FBSSerialQueue _performNext] + 192
    15  FrontBoardServices                  0x00000001061c5ac2 -[FBSSerialQueue _performNextFromRunLoopSource] + 45
    16  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000102d2ba31 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 17
    17  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000102d2195c __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 556
    18  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000102d20e13 __CFRunLoopRun + 867
    19  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000102d20828 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 488
    20  UIKit                               0x00000001033cf7cd -[UIApplication _run] + 402
    21  UIKit                               0x00000001033d4610 UIApplicationMain + 171
    22  libert2                             0x000000010175849f main + 111
    23  libdyld.dylib                       0x0000000104a4f92d start + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)
```

Here is the method:

```
-(void)salvaridnofirebase {
    Firebase *ref = [[Firebase alloc] initWithUrl:@"-myFirebaseURL-"];
    Firebase *usersRef = [ref childByAppendingPath:@"users"];
    NSDictionary *dict = @{ userid: userid };
    [usersRef updateChildValues:dict];
}
```

Comment: Tell me about the call to `salvaridnofirebase`.

Comment: I call it using [self salvaridnofirebase]. The method itself saves the id that is received from a facebook login into firebase.

Comment: Well the bug is in that method, and has nothing to do with outlets.  Please post the code.

Comment: -(void) salvaridnofirebase{
    Firebase *ref = [[Firebase alloc] initWithUrl:@"-myFirebaseURL-"];
    Firebase *usersRef = [ref childByAppendingPath:@"users"];
    NSDictionary *dict = @{
                           userid: userid
                           };
    
    [usersRef updateChildValues:dict];
}        The design doesn't look good in this comment, but... anyway, myFirebaseUrl is, obviously, my url and userid is a variable that has the id created when someone logins with facebook

Answer (score 0):

You simply need to be more defensive in your coding.  I expect the exception is in the line indicated below:

```
-(void)salvaridnofirebase {
    Firebase *ref = [[Firebase alloc] initWithUrl:@"-myFirebaseURL-"];
    Firebase *usersRef = [ref childByAppendingPath:@"users"];
    NSDictionary *dict = @{ userid: userid };    // HERE
    [usersRef updateChildValues:dict];
}
```

as `userid == nil`.  Therefore:

```
-(void)salvaridnofirebase {
    if (userid == nil) {
        NSLog(@"Cannot update userid as it's nil");
        return;
    }

    Firebase *ref = [[Firebase alloc] initWithUrl:@"-myFirebaseURL-"];
    Firebase *usersRef = [ref childByAppendingPath:@"users"];
    NSDictionary *dict = @{ userid: userid };
    [usersRef updateChildValues:dict];
}
```

better still don't call this method when `userid == nil`.  You have full control here.

Comment: Thanks mate, it worked and you helped a lot. I just gotta find now why userid didn't change before, but that's a whole new situation haha